# Cannot read property 'onBeforeNavigate' of undefined (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I simpley want to get the extension fired if the action on 'onBeforeNavigate' happens. But for no reason the extension always trows this error:

`Cannot read property 'onBeforeNavigate' of undefined`
Error is on this line `chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(setProxy);`

Here is my code so far:

**popup.js**

```
function setProxy(details){
    console.log("Got fired!\n");
}

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(setProxy);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Proxy Changer",
  "description": "This extension Changes the Proxy settings every time you load a website",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "notifications",
    "debugger",
    "background",
    "management",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": true,
    "js": ["jQuery.js", "popup.js"]
  }
}
```

I hate to say that I am very new to the Google Chrome Extension API but for me the Extension API is not working... I don't know what I am doing wrong..
I already watched to videos but still same error...

I would appreciate your help. Thank you and kind regards!

Comment: I would start from adding `webNavigation` to your manifest.json permissions as per the documentation - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation

Comment: Sadly, still same error...

Comment: NOW it is working :)

Comment: You need to reload the extension after editing the permissions.

Comment: But I have another question. Which function can I use which gets fired only once before the page gets loaded? This one gets fired multiple times..

Comment: I suggest using .onCommitted if you need a callback as soon as navigation is committed. [See more details here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted)

Comment: I want the function to be called only once on loading a website and I need to call the function before the website is loaded because I want to set a proxy!

Comment: `webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` is called only once per navigation. It may be called a second time if the page is redirected (I haven't tested that case). However, that is actually a separate navigation.

Answer (score 0):

just add "webNavigation" permission to Manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  ...
}
```

see documentation
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onCreatedNavigationTarget